# How to send a reset password email to user registered email in react native firebase?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, change-password, reset-password

i am using react native firebase in android and want to send forget or reset password email on registered email.Kindly someone share the code of reset password screen and email verification code in react native

Answer (score 0):

```
passwordReset: email => {
  return firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
},
```

For more details you can check...

> https://heartbeat.comet.ml/how-to-implement-forgot-password-feature-in-react-native-and-firebase-app-890b572d9759